# how make a new scheduler in xv6?

Tags: xv6

i am new to XV6 so be patient with me :D . 
i want to make a new scheduler and it is a mix of two scheduler the multi-level feedback queue (MLFQ) and another one the lottery scheduler.

The basic idea is simple: Build a two-level scheduler which first places jobs into the high-priority queue. When a job uses its time slice on the first queue, move it to the lower-priority queue; jobs on the lower-priority queue should run for two time slices before relinquishing the CPU.When there is more than one job on a queue, each should run in proportion to the number of tickets it has; the more tickets a process has, the more it runs. Each time slice, a randomized lottery determines the winner of the lottery; that winning process is the one that runs for that time slice.

i need a couple of new system calls to implement this scheduler.

The first is int settickets(int num) , which sets the number of tickets of the calling process. By default, each process should get one ticket; calling this routine makes it such that a process can raise the number of tickets it receives, and thus receive a higher proportion of CPU cycles. This routineshould return 0 if successful, and -1 otherwise (if, for example, the user passes in a number less than one).

The second is int getpinfo(struct pstat *) . This routine returns some basic information about each running process, including how many times it has been chosen to run and its process ID, and which queue it is on (high or low).

any help ? any lniks to help .

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and turn that large wall-of-text into readable paragraphs? It's hard to tell if there's even a question in there somewhere because there's such a jumbled mess. StackOverflow accepts paragraph breaks; you can even use the Enter key to add them when you're typing your question. You can also **preview it** just below the area where you're typing it in pretty much WYSIWYG fashion so you can see how it will look here. You stand a much better chance of getting help if your question can be understood. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite i am sorry i am new to stackOverFlow too :D but i need help doing this project [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/537/Fall2013/Projects/p2b.html)
could you please help me in it ?

Comment: Sorry, no. We don't do homework assignments here. You need to do some work yourself; if you run into problems you can then ask a **specific question** here about those problems. (You still need to break up your wall-of-text above, as I asked you before.)

Comment: no no i donot want to solve it for me i just want anyone to help how to start , any hint just how to start any links to guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: We don't do "links to guides" or links to tutorials or links to hints here, as it clearly says in the [help/on-topic] (see item #5 in the numbered list). If you have a **specific question**, and you ask it in a way we can read it, we can try to help, but we can't refer you to other sites. Google and Bing can do that, as they both specialize in searching for things and giving links to the search results. If you can't get started at all, ask your instructor or teaching assistant for help.

Comment: OK , there is a specific question i want to add an attribute int tickets to the process class , how and where i can do this ?

Comment: I realize that you're new to StackOverflow, but at least make some effort. **Questions** go in the question body, as do additional details you'd like to add. You can [edit] your question at any time to improve, add information, or clarify something. "How and where can I add an attibute int tickets to the process class?" is not a specific question. What have you tried to do to accomplish that task, and in what way did that effort not work? What error if any did you receive? **Make an effort to solve it yourself**, and then ask a **specific question** about a problem you encounter.

Comment: hey do you think that i am not working and waiting for someone to solve it for me , no you are wrong i am working on it for 5 hours now and there is a not bad progress but still not finished. anyway thanks for your concern.